# What is the best tool for parsing text in python?

Tags: python, parsing, text

What is the best tool for parsing English or Spanish text in python?

Is there any special library? What do you recommend? The usual regular expressions?

Comment: Does googling "parsing python" turn up nothing? (They're probably all mostly interchangeable unless you need to parse ambiguous grammars.)

Comment: What kind of parsing are you talking about? XML? Plain English? Config file? A custom config-type language thingamajig?

Comment: Plain English and Spanish

Comment: Then you're doing natural language processing. (Which also involves parsing but using that term might makes people think of "building a compiler".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For real (English/Spanish) text, try the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://nltk.org/).

For general parsing needs, [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is the library of choice.

I would advise against regex for all but the simplest tasks. Human language is hardly ever regular.

Comment: +1 for reading OP's minds and mention nltk

Comment: There's also the venerable ANTLR (v3 until someone finishes the Python target for v4) if you prefer a code generator approach. (Which might make it easier to step through the parser to see where it does something wrong.) And `pyPEG` seems like it makes it more straightforward to get an AST with attributes, although I might not be digging enough into `pyparsing`.

Comment: @millimoose: Thanks. I guess ANTLR is better suited for parsing code than for parsing text, isn't it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, I made the comment before the OP specified he needs to parse natural language. (I assumed "text" could means "code" but then again I'm in the middle of a compiler class.)